# Animating a UICollectionViewCell to take full width while pushing adjacent cells off screen

Tags: ios, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using a UICollectionView with a UICollectionViewFlowLayout to display a grid with 5 columns.

What I need to do now is to make it such that when someone taps on a certain cell, that cell expands horizontally (until it takes the full width of the screen). The cells to the left and right of it should get pushed off the screen.

A great example of this behaviour is in the Siri Contact Suggestions on the search screen of your iOS 9 devices.

[Siri Contacts Suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukXCD.png)

At this point, I have no clue what the best approach to do this is so I would appreciate if you could point me to the right direction.

Cheers